# How to customize hover behavior of Custom color palette for InkToolbarBallpointPenButton?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I am using the InkToolbar and have defined a InkToolbarBallpointPenButton within it. I have defined a custom color palette for this InkToolbarBallpointPenButton within the InkToolbar resources. However, when I run the below code and hover over the colors defined in this custom palette I can see the rgb values defined for the colors as opposed to the name of the colors.

```
<InkToolbar
    InitialControls="None">
    <InkToolbar.Resources>
        <BrushCollection x:Key="MyPalette">
              <SolidColorBrush Color="Red" />
              <SolidColorBrush Color="Blue" />
        </BrushCollection>
         </InkToolbar.Resources>
          <InkToolbarBallpointPenButton
               Palette="{StaticResource MyPalette}" />
      </InkToolbar>
```

How do I change the hover behavior to show the name of the color(ex: Blue , Red) as opposed to the RGB values here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click the `InkToolbarBallpointPenButton`, it will show an `InkToolbarPenConfigurationControl` which shows the colors that you pre-defined. The `ToolTip` you see in these colors is controlled by the system so we can't modify it.

But there is a workaround, we could make our own `ToolTips` on these colors to replace these `ToolTips` controlled by the system. Here are the steps that you need to do.

1. You need to find the default style of the `InkToolbarPenConfigurationControl`, you could find it in the `generic.xaml`. Copy the default style and put it into Application Resources.
2. Modify the `InkToolbarPenConfigurationControl` style in the Application Resources. You need to add a `ToolTip` to the `GridView` itemtemplate.
3. To show the color name, we need to create a value converter to convert the `SolidColorBrush` into a color name string. That will be used in the `ToolTip` as the color name.

I've made a sample here and you could refer to the following code:

Xaml style:

```
   <Application.Resources>
     <!--value converter-->
    <local:ColorConverter x:Key="ColorConverter" />
    <!--style-->
    <Style TargetType="InkToolbarPenConfigurationControl" >
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="InkToolbarPenConfigurationControl">
                    <Grid x:Name="RootElement" MinWidth="320">
                        <Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
                            <EntranceThemeTransition />
                        </Grid.ChildrenTransitions>

                        <Grid.Resources>
                            <Style x:Key="FlyoutStrokeWidthSelectorStyle" TargetType="Slider">
                                <Setter Property="IsThumbToolTipEnabled" Value="true" />
                            </Style>
                        </Grid.Resources>

                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="8" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="12" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="12" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="12" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="PenColorPaletteTitle" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Padding="12,0,12,0"
       Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" HighContrastAdjustment="None" Text="Colors" />
                        <!-- Color palette -->
                        <!-- Note: ItemsSource and selection are set in code-behind -->
                        <GridView x:Name="PenColorPalette" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Padding="4,0,4,2"
Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" >
                            <GridView.Resources>
                                <DataTemplate x:Key="HighContrastItemTemplate">
                                    <!-- Keep in sync with the GridView ItemTemplate, down below -->
                                    <Ellipse Margin="8,8,8,8" UseLayoutRounding="false" Fill="{Binding}"
     HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
     Stroke="{ThemeResource InkToolbarFlyoutItemBorderSelectedThemeBrush}"
     StrokeThickness="1"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridView.Resources>
                            <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" MaximumRowsOrColumns="6" />
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </GridView.ItemsPanel>
                            <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
                                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
                                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
                                    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="52" />
                                    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="52" />
                                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="52" />
                                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="52" />
                                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                    <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="{StaticResource UseSystemFocusVisuals}" />
                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="GridViewItem">
                                                <Grid>
                                                    <!--
                            GridViewItem visual states are documented here:
                            https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299127.aspx
                        -->
                                                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                                                    <Setter Target="ItemContent.Margin" Value="-2,-2,-2,-2" />
                                                                    <Setter Target="ItemBorder.Margin" Value="2,2,2,2" />
                                                                </VisualState.Setters>
                                                            </VisualState>
                                                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                                                    <Setter Target="ItemContent.Margin" Value="-2,-2,-2,-2" />
                                                                    <Setter Target="ItemBorder.Stroke" Value="{ThemeResource InkToolbarFlyoutItemBorderPressedThemeBrush}" />
                                                                    <Setter Target="ItemBorder.Margin" Value="2,2,2,2" />
                                                                </VisualState.Setters>
                                                            </VisualState>
                                                            <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                                                    <Setter Target="ItemContent.Margin" Value="2,2,2,2" />
                                                                    <Setter Target="ItemBorder.Stroke" Value="{ThemeResource InkToolbarFlyoutItemBorderSelectedThemeBrush}" />
                                                                </VisualState.Setters>
                                                            </VisualState>
                                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused" />
                                                            <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
                                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                    <Ellipse x:Name="ItemBorder"
     Margin="6,6,6,6" UseLayoutRounding="false"
     HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
     Fill="Transparent" Stroke="Transparent" StrokeThickness="2" />
                                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ItemContent" UseLayoutRounding="false" />
                                                </Grid>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <!-- Keep in sync with HighContrastItemTemplate item template above -->
                                    <Ellipse Margin="8,8,8,8" UseLayoutRounding="false"
     HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
     Fill="{Binding}" >
                                        <!--our own tooltip-->
                                        <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                            <ToolTip Content="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ColorConverter} }" />
                                        </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                    </Ellipse>

                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
                        </GridView>
                        <!-- StrokeWidth -->
                        <TextBlock x:Name="PenStrokeWidthTitle" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Padding="12,0,12,0"
       VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextBlockStyle}"
       Text="Size" HighContrastAdjustment="None" />
                        <Grid x:Name="StrokePreviewGrid" Grid.Row="6" UseLayoutRounding="false"
  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
  MinHeight="24">
                            <Canvas x:Name="StrokePreviewCanvas" Margin="12, 0, 12, 4" />

                        </Grid>
                        <Slider x:Name="PenStrokeWidthSlider"
    Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="0" Width="296" Height="44" Margin="12,0,12,0"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    Minimum="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=PenButton.MinStrokeWidth}"
    Maximum="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=PenButton.MaxStrokeWidth}"
    Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=PenButton.SelectedStrokeWidth, Mode=TwoWay}"
    Style="{StaticResource FlyoutStrokeWidthSelectorStyle}" />

                    </Grid>

                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

Value Converter:

```
 public class ColorConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        SolidColorBrush brush = value as SolidColorBrush;

        Color color = brush.Color;
        string selectedcolorname = null;
        foreach (var colorvalue in typeof(Colors).GetRuntimeProperties())
        {
            if ((Color)colorvalue.GetValue(null) == color)
            {
                selectedcolorname = colorvalue.Name;
            }
        }

        return selectedcolorname;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And the result looks like this:
[image]

Comment: This solution works wonderfully. Thanks !

Comment: Any specific reason to have the style defined under ApplicationResources and not page resources or GridResources ?

Comment: You can't get the InkToolbarPenConfigurationControl directly, the only way is to apply the style as a global style. To make the style a global style, you have to add it in the Application Resources instead of Page Resources. You could try to put it in the Page Resources, it won't work.

Comment: Got it! I noticed that the above solution works for Dark and light mode but it fails in High contrast. I tried debugging by putting break points in the converter code and noticed it doesn't hit in high contrast. Any idea as to why this might be the case?